# Except condition in selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I was thinking if there is an `except`  in selenium my research yielded me with no results. I want to get whatever is present in body tag but not in a division tag where id = "main' . Is it possible in selenium?

EDIT: I know how to get content if I know exactly what I am searching for. But in this scenario, I just want all the text not in any tag

Here is an html sample

```
<head></head>   
<body>
Text I want

<div id ="main"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: To clarify, when you say "But in this scenario, I just want all the text not in any tag" do you mean you just want ALL text that is on the webpage?

Comment: No just the "Text I want" which can vary. It is inside <body> tag but NOT inside ANY other tag and not inside the div tag

Comment: If I follow, this isn't something you can do with Selenium.

Comment: Basically, I want any text seen above main tag is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately not, any time you try and get the text component from the `<body>` it will get all the text between `<body>` and `</body>`, it will include whatever is in the `<div>` as well.

Comment: Oh bummer! I know about including everything but now I'll have to think of clever ways of finding it. We get php errors which are within the body tags and not within any div tag or so, so I was hoping to catch them rather than manual work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (not tested code written in C#)

```
var element = Driver.FindElement(By.Tagname("body"));
var myText = element.GetAttribute("value");
```

Comment: But the text that I want can be anything! It doesn't have to be "value" . Your code will help if I am searching for "value"

Comment: @OctavianRox the above would actually return whatever the attribute 'value' is equal too. Not what you want but helpful to know anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is very useful :) I have used it before ignore my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

You can write Xpath like this:

`//body/text()`

To get only text from body tag.